# Random number generator generating the wrong set of numbers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, random

I'm attempting to make a program that generates an array of random numbers where no two cells contain the same number within a given range.

Example: asking it to make an array of 4 should yield something like: `4 2 1 3`, instead what I get is this: `4 2 1360726912 245694014`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

// generates a random number within a given range
int random(int from, int to) {
  int 
    high = to + 1,
    low = from;

  return (rand() % high - low) + low;
}

// returns a random number different from any number in the array
int gen_different(int arr_len, int arr[]) {
  int rand_val = random(1, arr_len);
  int matches = FALSE;
  for(int i = 0; i < arr_len; i++) {
    if(rand_val == arr[i]) matches = TRUE;
  }

  if(matches) gen_different(arr_len, arr);
  return rand_val;
}

// generates an array with a given number of cells, containing all different numbers
void gen_arr(int count, int arr[]) {
  for(int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    arr[i] = gen_different(count, arr);
}

int main() {
  srand(time(NULL));
  printf("Please enter an array number: ");
  int num = 0;
  scanf("%d", &num);
  int* arr[num];
  gen_arr(num, arr);

  for(int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
  }

  printf("\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I get that my issue has something to do with pointers, but I'm not quite sure what I should change to make it work. Any help?

Comment: Will the range always be the same as of the array, i.e. if the array if is 15 elements long, then the range for the random numbers is [1,15]?   If this is the case, isn't easier to initialize the array elements with their index values and then shuffle the array?

Comment: @thurizas you make a valid point

Comment: This post title made me laugh!  Had to come here and take a look cuz my first thought was "how does one know whether a random number generator produced the right number?"

Comment: @ChrisCaviness it's easy to see from the context, no?

Comment: Yeah, after I looked at it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are initializing arr[num] as

```
int* arr[num]; //array of pointers to integers
```

it should be like

```
int arr[num]; ////array of integers
```

Comment: solving this problem just brings up another issue; the array either contains duplicates, which it shouldn't; or it segfaults, any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

I think that:

```
 int* arr[num];
```

is not what you want.  Try

```
 int arr[num];
```

(Note this is not legal C before C99)

Comment: Thanks, made my comment more precise.

Answer (score 1):

One possible problem is you are declaring your array as a pointer to an array

```
int* arr[num];
```

this is the same as:

```
int ** arr;
```

You should actually use

```
int arr[num];
```

As you are expecting an array in your functions.

Answer (score 0):

Expression:

```
(rand() % high - low) + low
```

looks suspect as it is the same as `rand() % high`.

Did you mean:

```
(rand() % (high - low)) + low
```

?

Comment: didn't change anything, but yes that's what I meant

Comment: @ElectricCoffee It would change if `low > 0`. You may not see difference because your test is not repeatable because of `srand(time(NULL));`.